# How to get list of installed printers on Linux with .NET 6

Tags: .net, linux, printing, deprecation-warning

Because in .NET 6, [System.Drawing is windows only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/system-drawing-common-windows-only), we can use SkiaSharp or ImageSharp to handle Images on Linux.

But we cannot handle Printing. For example this:

```cs
using System.Drawing.Printing;

namespace Test;
public class PrintersController
{
    public void Get()
    {
        var installedPrinters = PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters.Cast<string>();
    }
}
```

I get an exception if this is used in Linux Docker container:

`The type initializer for 'System.Drawing.Printing.PrintingServices' threw an exception`

I added `System.Drawing.EnabledUnixSupport: true` in runtimeconfig.json for now and it's working fine, but this is going away in .NET 7.

Any ideas?